# how to stop a garage door from self opening

Tags: garage

I have a chamberlain garage door. I bought a new remote and programmed it using the instructions provided. The remote works fine, but now the garage door opens on its own approx every 30 mins. How do I prevent this?

Comment: Chamberlain has amazing customer support, you should call them.  They don't care if you are in or out of warranty.

Comment: After putting down the door remove the battery from the remote(s) if the door doesn't open it shows one of the remotes is triggering. If it continues to open spontaneously, then it's not your remote(s).